# CSS Issue in IE Only

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I can't for the life of me figure out why specifying a image as a background for a link that it would look like this for IE and look the way it should for every other browser. The top image is IE and the bottom is every other browser. Look at the text, it is supposed to have a transparent PNG behind it and I set it to repeat. Here is the URL if you want to see the code: http://flesheatingzipper.com

[image]

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, it renders correctly in IE9. (Which also makes it so I can't troubleshoot on this box sorry)

Comment: Really should be on StackOverflow. Voting to move

Comment: Having problems with IE is expected and normal. IE is the worst browser on the planet (yes, including IE9).

Comment: I lost all hope for IE a loooong time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a 2x2px png image for the repeated background, looks like it is the bug described here: http://www.rachaelarnold.com/dev/archive/ie-gradient-bug-with-png-24

Comment: This worked like a champ! Thanks, I've never run into this issue before.

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that this isn't a CSS issue.  My guess is that its a png issue.  Depending on which version of IE you're using the rendering will be different.  The early days of PNG in IE were not pretty.  Especially with regards to transparency.  I'm not sure why you're using this approach.  I would recommend using a fully-css approach instead.  You should use the following css properties to adjust a css background color to the desired transparency:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* internet explorer */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;      /* khtml, old safari */
-moz-opacity: 0.5;       /* mozilla, netscape */
opacity: 0.5;           /* fx, safari, opera */
```

I think you'll find this approach to be much cleaner and easier in the long run with more universal output.

EDIT:  As it was pointed out there is a glitch with my above recommended approach however it might be easier to get your current approach working using the techniques described here: http://www.daltonlp.com/view/217

Comment: I meant to indicate that IE started off bad and didn't improve very quickly.  IE will probably always be the bane of CSS developers.

Comment: opacity adjusts the object and all it contains, so will also make the text transparent. Not likely what you want. You could, however, use an RGBA color for the background. Again, won't work in IE, though.

Comment: This is true.  I wasn't thinking about that. Perhaps you could apply the opacity to a container that has the background color in it then again apply the opacity (only this time to have 100% opacity instead of partial) to a container containing the text.  Not sure if that will work completely.  But if it does let me know cuz I'm curious!  lol.

Comment: If what I just suggested doesn't work if you float the element containing the text and set it to full opacity then tweak the background color element so that it resizes to still contain the float (I forget the hack for this at the moment... overflow:auto?) then that should for sure work.  I'd try the first approach first though.  Once you start throwing floats in there it gets messy sometimes.

Comment: for that to work if the parent container is .5, then the child container would have to have an opacity of 2. So, that won't work, unfortunately. If using opacity, you can't nest anything that you don't want to also inherit that opacity setting.

Comment: Well I haven't personally tried to play with it... but I think floating the inner element should cut the cord with the parent on this issue... I could be wrong though.

Comment: http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

Comment: Floating does not separate the parent/child CSS inheritance relationship. It just takes it out of the document flow. Note that the solution you linked to recommends using RGBA colors instead.

Comment: Yes... I was throwing out other alternatives.  I've also added a link to my original answer which I think is the better solution for him.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I went the easy route and used the answer from Jasuten and made it 2x2 instead of 1x1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a solid color, I'd avoid using an image at all and use an RGBA color:

http://24ways.org/2009/working-with-rgba-colour

As for IE, you don't say which version, but IE6 and IE7 both have very wonky support for alpha transparency in PNG files. There are a variety of methods to get them working, though most still have trouble repeating as backgrounds. You could try, instead of repeating a small image, just using one larger image.

Or, be pragmatic. Use the RGBA and just let IE degrade into a solid color. We need to stop babying IE users ;)